# Javascript Hover Text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a hover that shows a list to the user and reminds the user what we can accept.

```
<div class="proofresidencytip" style="display:inline-block;">
  Hover Picture
</div>

$(".proofresidencytip").hover(
        function(){
            var message = "Please submit a copy of one of the following:";
            var div = '<div class="rvtooltips">'+message+'</div>';
            $(this).append(div);
            $(this).find(".rvtooltips").fadeIn("fast");

        },
        function(){
            var tt = $(this).find(".rvtooltips");
            tt.fadeOut("fast", function(){
                tt.remove();
            });
        }
    );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jw6zc4hf/

I am trying to figure out how I can list the items in `var message`. Whenever i try using `<br>` or any other html code it just breaks and doesnt show the message at all. How can I display new lines and the list of items in the hover?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You could use the `<ul>` element for this, which is semantically the most appropriate element to contain list content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what the problem is? You can place `<br>` into `message` just fine:

```js
$(".proofresidencytip").hover(
        function(){
            var message = "Please submit a copy of one of the following:<br>a<br>b";
            var div = '<div class="rvtooltips">'+message+'</div>';
            $(this).append(div);
            $(this).find(".rvtooltips").fadeIn("fast");

        },
        function(){
            var tt = $(this).find(".rvtooltips");
            tt.fadeOut("fast", function(){
                tt.remove();
            });
        }
    );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="proofresidencytip" style="display:inline-block;">
  Hover Picture
</div>
```

If you have simplified your example in order to post the question on SO, you may have omitted some relevant CSS. If your `proofresidencytip` class has a set height, for example, it cannot easily expand. Make sure to set `padding`, `line-height`, perhaps `min-height`, but NOT `height` nor `overflow: none`.

Comment: @DavidBrierton Well, your tooltip is set to `text-align: center`, so naturally the lines are all centred. As suggested in the comment on your question, you should probably use a `<ul>` for a list. So instead of using textual bullet points (`-`) and line breaks (`<br>`), wrap the list in `<ul>...</ul>` and each item in `<li>...</li>`. By default this already aligns the bullet points, but you can apply more CSS to the `ul` or `li` to make it look better (set the correct padding, etc).